# why is function pointer definition different from normal pointer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

In C++, when you declare pointer, normaly the syntax is

```
datatype* ptr;
```

But when you declare function pointer, you write

```
datatype (*ptr) (param1, param2);
```

`datatype*` means pointer to datatype, `*ptr` means a content pointer points to.

So it's confusing why it is `datatype (*ptr)`, not `datatype* ptr`when you declare function pointer.

Thank you.

Comment: `datatype *(ptr) (param1, param2);` Would be a function returning a pointer.

Comment: C and C++ are strictly typed languages. The compiler needs to be able to differentiate between a pointer to a data type versus a pointer to a function, and it needs to know the full signature of the type of function being pointed at so it can actually call functions via such a pointer.

Comment: `datatype (*ptr);` is a perfectly valid declaration and is equivalent to `datatype* ptr;`; it just has redundant parentheses.  In the case of the function pointer, the parentheses are required to override the higher precedence of the function arguments -- postfix operators are always higher precedence than prefix in C++.